# How to summarize all possible combinations of variables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas, teradata

I am trying to summarize the count based on the all possible combinations of variables. Here is an example data:
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also is it related to R or SQL Server / Teradata?

Comment: Any environment would work. I was able to transpose variables. But then really couldn't figure out  how to build a script so that it summarizes data as I expect. Any suggestion?

Comment: @poshan Please post better sample output. WIthout `D` and with `2^3-1` rows (`A`, `B`,`C`,`A,B`,`A,C`,`B,C`,`A,B,C`).

Comment: You can use `proc summary` in SAS to do exactly what you a looking for.  I'd post an answer but the question is closed.

Comment: @Robert Penridge that would be great. Thank you

Comment: Really not that broad and easy to solve: use case statements in a  CTE to turn a, b, and c into null if 0 or their name e.g. `case a when 0 then null else 'a' end a` then `select a, b, c, count(id) cnt from the_cte group by cube (a,b,c) having (a is not null or grouping(a) = 1) and (b is not null or grouping(b) = 1) and (c is not null or grouping(c) = 1) and grouping_id(a,b,c) <> 7`

Comment: @poshan in your sample results you left out just c which would have a count of 1

Comment: rextester link for above code: http://rextester.com/YRJ10544

Comment: @Sentinel Nice approach :)

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly May I ask why do you think this question is too broad?

Comment: @lad2025 Thanks, It's also easy to add columns, the amount of effort is minimal and scales linearly with the number of columns (add appropriate reference in the CTE, output projection, cube clause, having and order by clauses.  the number of potential output rows, however, grows exponentially with number of columns.

Comment: @Henrik, How is this question too broad? Please consider voting to reopen this question "All possible combinations" refers to the mathematical concept of combinations/permutations, not all possible ways to answer the question.

Comment: A simple clear question is not too broad despite the answer involving several steps.  For SAS only, the LEXCOMB function can help construct statement parts that can be used in a generated SQL statement that unions each combinations distinct counts.    Another technique that would use a single pass over the data in a data step can be coded using hash of hashes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this sort of query using some of the built in aggregate tools is quite straight forward.

First off setup some sample data based on your sample image:

```
declare @Table1 as table
    ([id] int, [a] int, [b] int, [c] int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    ([id], [a], [b], [c])
VALUES
    (10001, 1, 3, 3),
    (10002, 0, 0, 0),
    (10003, 3, 6, 0),
    (10004, 7, 0, 0),
    (10005, 0, 0, 0)
;
```

Since you want the count of IDs for each possible combination of non zero attributes A, B, and C, the first step is eliminate the zeros and convert the non zero values to a single value we can summarize on, in this case I'll use the attributes name.  After that it's a simple matter of performing the aggregate, using the `CUBE` clause in the group by statement to generate the combinations. Lastly in the having clause prune out the unwanted summations.  Mostly that's just ignoring the null values in the attributes, and optionally removing the grand summary (count of all rows)

```
with t1 as (
select case a when 0 then null else 'a' end a
     , case b when 0 then null else 'b' end b
     , case c when 0 then null else 'c' end c
     , id
  from @Table1
)
select a, b, c, count(id) cnt
  from t1
  group by cube(a,b,c)
  having (a is not null or grouping(a) = 1) -- For each attribute
     and (b is not null or grouping(b) = 1) -- only allow nulls as
     and (c is not null or grouping(c) = 1) -- a result of grouping.
     and grouping_id(a,b,c) <> 7  -- exclude the grand total
  order by grouping_id(a,b,c);
```

Here are the results:

```
    a       b       c       cnt
1   a       b       c       1
2   a       b       NULL    2
3   a       NULL    c       1
4   a       NULL    NULL    3
5   NULL    b       c       1
6   NULL    b       NULL    2
7   NULL    NULL    c       1
```

And finally my original rextester link: http://rextester.com/YRJ10544

@lad2025 Here's a dynamic version (sorry my SQL Server skills aren't as strong as my Oracle skills, but it works). Just set the correct values for @Table and @col and it should work as long as all other columns are numeric attributes:

```
declare @sql varchar(max), @table varchar(30), @col varchar(30);
set @table = 'Table1';
set @col = 'id';
with x(object_id, column_id, name, names, proj, pred, max_col, cnt) 
  as (
    select object_id, column_id, name, cast(name as varchar(max))
     , cast('case '+name+' when 0 then null else '''+name+''' end '+name as varchar(4000))
     , cast('('+name+' is not null or grouping('+name+') = 1)' as varchar(4000))
     , (select max(column_id) from sys.columns m where m.object_id = c.object_id and m.name <>'ID')
     , 1
     from sys.columns c
    where object_id = OBJECT_ID(@Table)
      and column_id = (select min(column_id) from sys.columns m where m.object_id = c.object_id and m.name <> @col)
    union all
    select x.object_id, c.column_id, c.name, cast(x.names+', '+c.name as varchar(max))
     , cast(proj+char(13)+char(10)+'     , case '+c.name+' when 0 then null else '''+c.name+''' end '+c.name as varchar(4000))
     , cast(pred+char(13)+char(10)+'   and ('+c.name+' is not null or grouping('+c.name+') = 1)' as varchar(4000))
     , max_col
     , cnt+1
      from x join sys.columns c on c.object_id = x.object_id and c.column_id = x.column_id+1
)
select @sql='with t1 as (
select '+proj+'
     , '+@col+'
  from '+@Table+'
)
select '+names+'
     , count('+@col+') cnt 
  from t1
 group by cube('+names+')
having '+pred+'
   and grouping_id('+names+') <> '+cast(power(2,cnt)-1 as varchar(10))+'
 order by grouping_id('+names+');'
  from x where column_id = max_col;

select @sql sql;
exec (@sql);
```

**[Rextester](http://rextester.com/QDAE68294)**

Comment: what I realized is that the approach @lad2025 suggested is not compatible for STRING_AGG function in my version of SQL SERVER. This approach is more readable and less techy and runs in my version of SQL server. All I have to do is to add a piece of code that does string concat.  Thank you guys for your wonderful suggestion.

Comment: @Sentinel  Great answer Consider to make it fully dynamic and it will be excellent :) The funny thing is that I've also thought about GROUP BY CUBE but I've chosen unpivot approach.

Comment: @lad2025 does that meet with your approval?

Answer (score 1):

Poshan:

As Robert stated, SUMMARY can be used to count combinations.  A second SUMMARY can count the computed types.  One difficulty is ignoring the combinations that involve a zero value.  If they can be converted to missings the processing is much cleaner.  Presuming zeros converted to missing, this code would count distinct combinations:

```
proc summary noprint data=have;
  class v2-v4 s1;
  output out=counts_eachCombo;
run;

proc summary noprint data=counts_eachCombo(rename=_type_=combo_type);
  class combo_type;
  output out=counts_eachClassType;
run;
```

You can see how the use of a CLASS variable in a combination determines the *TYPE*, and the class variables can be of mixed type (numeric, character)

A different 'home-grown' approach that does not use SUMMARY can use data step with LEXCOMB to compute each combination and SQL with into / separated to generate a SQL statement that will count each distinctly.

Note: The following code contains macro varListEval for resolving a [SAS variable list](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=p0wphcpsfgx6o7n1sjtqzizp1n39.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) to individual variable names.

```
%macro makeHave(n=,m=,maxval=&m*4,prob0=0.25);

  data have;
    do id = 1 to &n;
      array v v1-v&m;
      do over v;
        if ranuni(123) < &prob0 then v = 0; else v = ceil(&maxval*ranuni(123));
      end;
      s1 = byte(65+5*ranuni(123));
      output;
    end;
  run;

%mend;

%makeHave (n=100,m=5,maxval=15)

%macro varListEval (data=, var=);
  %* resolve a SAS variable list to individual variable names;
  %local dsid dsid2 i name num;
  %let dsid = %sysfunc(open(&data));
  %if &dsid %then %do;
    %let dsid2 = %sysfunc(open(&data(keep=&var)));
    %if &dsid2 %then %do;
      %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(attrn(&dsid,nvar));
        %let name = %sysfunc(varname(&dsid,&i));
        %let num = %sysfunc(varnum(&dsid2,&name));
        %if &num %then "&NAME";
      %end;
      %let dsid2 = %sysfunc(close(&dsid2));
    %end;
    %let dsid = %sysfunc(close(&dsid));
  %end;
  %else
    %put %sysfunc(sysmsg());
%mend;

%macro combosUCounts(data=, var=);
  %local vars n;
  %let vars = %varListEval(data=&data, var=&var);

  %let n = %eval(1 + %sysfunc(count(&vars,%str(" ")));

  * compute combination selectors and criteria;
  data combos;
    array _names (&n) $32 (&vars);
    array _combos (&n) $32;
    array _comboCriterias (&n) $200;

    length _selector $32000;
    length _criteria $32000;

    if 0 then set &data; %* prep PDV for vname;

    do _k = 1 to &n;
      do _j = 1 to comb(&n,_k);
        _rc = lexcomb(_j,_k, of _names[*]);
        do _p = 1 to _k;
          _combos(_p) = _names(_p);
          if vtypex(_names(_p)) = 'C' 
            then _comboCriterias(_p) = trim(_names(_p)) || " is not null and " || trim(_names(_p)) || " ne ''";
            else _comboCriterias(_p) = trim(_names(_p)) || " is not null and " || trim(_names(_p)) || " ne 0";
        end;
        _selector = catx(",", of _combos:);
        _criteria = catx(" and ", of _comboCriterias:);
        output;
      end;
    end;

    stop;
  run;

  %local union;

  proc sql noprint;
    * generate SQL statement that uses combination selectors and criteria;
    select "select "
    || quote(trim(_selector))
    || " as combo" 
    || ", "
    || "count(*) as uCount from (select distinct "
    || trim(_selector)
    || " from &data where "
    || trim(_criteria)
    || ")"
    into :union separated by " UNION "
    from combos
    ;

    * perform the generated SQL statement;
    create table comboCounts as
    &union;

    /* %put union=%superq(union); */
  quit;
%mend;

options mprint nosymbolgen;
%combosUCounts(data=have, var=v2-v4);
%combosUCounts(data=have, var=v2-v4 s1);

%put NOTE: Done;
/*
data _null_;
put %varListEval(data=have, var=v2-v4) ;
run;
*/
```

Comment: Hello Richard, this macro works great! Thank you. If I want to filter out all the combos with uCOunt =0, where do I add that filter? Would you be able to  add that piece of information in this macro? I appreciate for this. Thank you

Comment: Hi Poshan:  Since you are using SAS, you can use the data set option where= to apply the desired criteria.  createComboCount(where=(uCount > 0)) as ... [ Cool thing about the where= option is that it can be used to select  rows in both input and output data sets ].  If you prefer to not use the where= option, a subquery can be used.  create ... as select * from (&union) where uCount > 0;

Answer (score 0):

Naive approach `SQL Server` version (I've assumed that we always have 3 columns so there will be 2^3-1 rows):

```
SELECT 'A' AS combination, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a > 0 THEN a ELSE NULL END) AS cnt FROM t
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'B', COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN b > 0 THEN a ELSE NULL END) FROM t
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'C', COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c > 0 THEN a ELSE NULL END) FROM t
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A,B', COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a > 0 THEN CAST(a AS VARCHAR(10)) ELSE NULL END 
                     + ',' + CASE WHEN b > 0 THEN CAST(b AS VARCHAR(10)) ELSE NULL END) FROM t
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A,C', COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a > 0 THEN CAST(a AS VARCHAR(10)) ELSE NULL END 
                     + ',' + CASE WHEN c > 0 THEN CAST(c AS VARCHAR(10)) ELSE NULL END) FROM t
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B,C', COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN b > 0 THEN CAST(b AS VARCHAR(10)) ELSE NULL END 
                     + ',' + CASE WHEN c > 0 THEN CAST(c AS VARCHAR(10)) ELSE NULL END) FROM t
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A,B,C', COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a > 0 THEN CAST(a AS VARCHAR(10)) ELSE NULL END 
                     + ',' + CASE WHEN b > 0 THEN CAST(b AS VARCHAR(10)) ELSE NULL END
                     + ',' + CASE WHEN c > 0 THEN CAST(c AS VARCHAR(10)) ELSE NULL END ) FROM t
ORDER BY combination
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/WJKC9622)**

---

**EDIT:**

Same as above but more concise:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID
          ,CAST(NULLIF(a,0) AS VARCHAR(10)) a
          ,CAST(NULLIF(b,0) AS VARCHAR(10)) b
          ,CAST(NULLIF(c,0) AS VARCHAR(10)) c 
    FROM t
)
SELECT 'A' AS combination, COUNT(DISTINCT a) AS cnt FROM cte UNION ALL 
SELECT 'B', COUNT(DISTINCT b) FROM cte UNION ALL 
SELECT 'C', COUNT(DISTINCT c) FROM cte UNION ALL
SELECT 'A,B', COUNT(DISTINCT a + ',' + b) FROM cte UNION ALL
SELECT 'A,C', COUNT(DISTINCT a + ',' + c) FROM cte UNION ALL
SELECT 'B,C', COUNT(DISTINCT b + ',' + c) FROM cte UNION ALL
SELECT 'A,B,C', COUNT(DISTINCT a + ',' + b + ',' + c ) FROM cte ;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/RGPI60616)**

---

**EDIT 2**

Using `UNPIVOT`:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT ID
               ,CAST(IIF(a!=0,1,NULL) AS VARCHAR(10)) a
               ,CAST(IIF(b!=0,1,NULL) AS VARCHAR(10)) b
               ,CAST(IIF(c!=0,1,NULL) AS VARCHAR(10)) c 
            FROM t)
SELECT combination, [count]
FROM (SELECT  a=COUNT(a), b=COUNT(b), c=COUNT(c)
           , ab=COUNT(a+b), ac=COUNT(a+c), bc=COUNT(b+c), abc=COUNT(a+b+c)
      FROM cte) s
UNPIVOT ([count] FOR combination IN (a,b,c,ab,ac,bc,abc))AS unpvt
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/ZMJOPJ43834)**

---

## EDIT FINAL APPROACH

> I appreciate your approach. **I have more than 3 variables in my actual dataset and do you think we can generate all possible combinations programatically rather than the hard coding them!** May be your second approach will cover that :

SQL is a bit clumsy to do this kind of operation, but I want to show it is possible.

```
CREATE TABLE t(id INT, a INT, b INT, c INT);

INSERT INTO t
SELECT 10001,1,3,3 UNION
SELECT 10002,0,0,0 UNION
SELECT 10003,3,6,0 UNION
SELECT 10004,7,0,0 UNION
SELECT 10005,0,0,0;

DECLARE @Sample AS TABLE 
(
    item_id     tinyint IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
    item        nvarchar(500) NOT NULL,
    bit_value   AS  CONVERT ( integer, POWER(2, item_id - 1) )
                PERSISTED UNIQUE CLUSTERED
);    

INSERT INTO @Sample
SELECT name
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('t')
  AND name != 'id';

DECLARE @max integer = POWER(2, ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Sample AS s)) - 1;
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @cols_casted NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @cols_count NVARCHAR(MAX);


;WITH
  Pass0 as (select 1 as C union all select 1), --2 rows
  Pass1 as (select 1 as C from Pass0 as A, Pass0 as B),--4 rows
  Pass2 as (select 1 as C from Pass1 as A, Pass1 as B),--16 rows
  Pass3 as (select 1 as C from Pass2 as A, Pass2 as B),--256 rows
  Pass4 as (select 1 as C from Pass3 as A, Pass3 as B),--65536 rows
  Tally as (select row_number() over(order by C) as n from Pass4)
, cte AS (SELECT
    combination =
        STUFF
        (
            (
                SELECT ',' + s.item 
                FROM @Sample AS s
                WHERE
                    n.n & s.bit_value = s.bit_value
                ORDER BY
                    s.bit_value
                FOR XML 
                    PATH (''),
                    TYPE                    
            ).value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(8000)'), 1, 1, ''
        )
FROM Tally AS N
WHERE N.n BETWEEN 1 AND @max
)
SELECT @cols = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(combination),',')
      ,@cols_count = STRING_AGG(FORMATMESSAGE('[%s]=COUNT(DISTINCT %s)'
                    ,combination,REPLACE(combination, ',', ' + '','' +') ),',')
FROM cte;

SELECT 
  @cols_casted = STRING_AGG(FORMATMESSAGE('CAST(NULLIF(%s,0) AS VARCHAR(10)) %s'
                 ,name, name), ',')
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('t')
  AND name != 'id';
  
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql =
'SELECT combination, [count]
FROM (SELECT  <cols_count>
      FROM (SELECT ID, <cols_casted> FROM t )cte) s
UNPIVOT ([count] FOR combination IN (<cols>))AS unpvt';

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '<cols_casted>', @cols_casted);
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '<cols_count>', @cols_count);
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '<cols>', @cols);

SELECT @sql;
EXEC (@sql);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8804866d981a03a10a5c7e7bffc9bdb0)**

**[DBFiddle Demo with 4 variables](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=18a229773d96cea006e5aa50dc3af40b)**

Comment: For downvoter: Question is very clear, but provided output is somehow wrong. This is my first approach and I will provide better alternatives using perhaps GROUP BY CUBE or PIVOT/UNPIVOT + dynamic SQL

Comment: I appreciate your approach. I have more than 3 variables in my actual dataset and do you think we can generate all possible combinations programatically rather than the hard coding them! May be your second approach will cover that :)

Comment: @poshan Using Dynamic-SQL and metadata it is doable. (Read from sys.columns -> generate all possible combination of columns -> build SQL query).

Comment: thank you. This satisfies what I am looking for. I appreciate your help.