# Frequency of each unique combination in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

In a dataset (N=6000) I would like to analyse how often combinations of (15 dummy)variables occur.

```
ID       Var1        Var2       Var3    Var15

1          1          0          0        1

2          0          1          1        1

3          1          0          0        0

6000       1          0          0        0
```

For this example what I would like to see is that the combination 1000 occurs twice, 1001 occurs once, and 0111 occurs also once.

The only way I can think up is compute a variable for each possible combination...

Is there an elegant and efficient way to do this?

I have read through 
[How to summarize all possible combinations of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46837639/how-to-summarize-all-possible-combinations-of-variables) But that is a slightly different question and [Aggregating Tally counters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143575/aggregating-tally-counters) transcends my knowledge (but if that is the answer to my question, I will go through it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `count` like this:

```
df = read.table(text = "
ID       Var1        Var2       Var3    Var15
1          1          0          0        1
2          0          1          1        1
3          1          0          0        0
6000       1          0          0        0
", header=T)

library(dplyr)

df %>% count(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var15)

# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#     Var1  Var2  Var3 Var15     n
#    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     0     1     1     1     1
# 2     1     0     0     0     2
# 3     1     0     0     1     1
```

Or use `count_` if you don't want to type (many) column names:

```
input_names = names(df)[-1]  # select all column names apart from 1st one

df %>% count_(input_names)

# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#    Var1  Var2  Var3 Var15     n
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     0     1     1     1     1
# 2     1     0     0     0     2
# 3     1     0     0     1     1
```

If you want to group your variables and create a single (combo) variable you can do this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

input_names = names(df)[-1]

df %>% count_(input_names) %>% unite_("ComboVar",input_names,sep="")

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   ComboVar     n
# * <chr>    <int>
# 1 0111         1
# 2 1000         2
# 3 1001         1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. I will try it.

Comment: Works nicely Thank you again!

Comment: I am confused as to how this helps as it does not contain combinations with 0 occurrences?

Comment: @cs0815 They clearly specified how they want their output to look like and my answer is based on that. You should try `library(tidyverse);
df %>% count(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var15) %>% complete(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var15, fill = list(n = 0))` to get zero values for combinations that don't exist.

Comment: @AntoniosK thanks - must have overlooked that part - sorry

Answer (score 3):

Using the `dplyr` package, you could have:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var15) %>% tally
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R solution is to use `table`. Using AntoniosK's example df:

```
df = read.table(text = "
ID       Var1        Var2       Var3    Var15
1          1          0          0        1
2          0          1          1        1
3          1          0          0        0
6000       1          0          0        0
", header=T)

res <- as.data.frame(table(df[,2:5]))

#> res
#   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var15 Freq
#1     0    0    0     0    0
#2     1    0    0     0    2
#3     0    1    0     0    0
#4     1    1    0     0    0
#5     0    0    1     0    0
#6     1    0    1     0    0
#7     0    1    1     0    0
#8     1    1    1     0    0
#9     0    0    0     1    0
#10    1    0    0     1    1
#11    0    1    0     1    0
#12    1    1    0     1    0
#13    0    0    1     1    0
#14    1    0    1     1    0
#15    0    1    1     1    1
#16    1    1    1     1    0
```

Unlike the other examples, this gives you zero frequencies. If you do not want those zero frequency examples, then you can simply do:

```
res[res$Freq>0,]
```

Answer (score 1):

The SPSS solution is also to simply aggregate.
The following syntax will put the count in a new dataset:

```
DATASET DECLARE comb.
AGGREGATE  /OUTFILE='comb' /BREAK=var1 to var15 /Noccurences=N.
```

You can also add the count to the present dataset like this:

```
AGGREGATE /OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES /BREAK=var1 var2 var3 /Noccurences=N.
```

Answer (score 1):

A `plyr` option:

```
plyr::count(df[-1])

#   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var15 freq
#1    0    1    1     1    1
#2    1    0    0     0    2
#3    1    0    0     1    1
```