# Calculate frequency of combination of strings

Tags: r, awk

I have a list of number identifiers followed by one or more strings. I would like to calculate for each identifier the longest combination of associated strings that were also present for another identifier. Then also the number of strings associated with each identifier.

E.g.

```
1   AAA    BBBA    ACA    CCD    ABADA
2   AAA    ACA     CCD
3   AAB    BBAC    DDAD
4   AAA    ACA     DDAD   CCD
5   AAA    ACA     DDAD   CCD
```

Would result in:

```
ID  Longest Combo  Number of strings  
1         3               5
2         3               3
3         1               3
4         4               4
5         4               4
```

Explanation of results for clarity:

```
1 - AAA, ACA and CCD present in 2 so longest combo is 3.
2 - AAA, ACA and CCD present in 1 so longest combo is 3.
3 - DDAD present in 4 and 5 so longest combo is 1.
4 - AAA, ACA, DDAD and CCD present in 5 so longest combo is 4.
5 - AAA, ACA, DDAD and CCD present in 4 so longest combo is 4.
```

Normally I can try and hack something together myself but have hit a wall with this one - not sure where to even begin. The analysis to get to this point takes place in awk so bash would be ideal but potentially this is a job better suited to R?

I was trying to format my data in accordance with this question [Frequency of each unique combination in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48562288/frequency-of-each-unique-combination-in-data-frame) without success.

Any help would be most appreciated.

There are approximately 3000 identifiers, each with between 1-15 strings.

Comment: Wow. When you ask a question you ask a doozie, doncha? XD

Comment: How big is this file?

Comment: Only one of the strings is found so longest combo is 1. Sorry I should clarify longest combo is number of strings not the identifier. I've added length of the file to the original!

Comment: I figured it out and deleted my stupid question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know R, don't like awk. How about a bash solution? XD

> edited to include comments. Made a few minor changes and found one possibly significant caveat. Note that is you have an AAA *and* an AAAA that the current code might give you a false match because `AAAA` matches `*AAA*`. Swap in the new (but still commented) line if that's so, it will still work, and will handle that possibility.

```
$: cat proc
#! /bin/env bash

# predeclare these as associative arrays - string-based dictionary lookups
declare -A cnt=() set=() lookup=() combos=() hitlst=() hitcnt=() hitid=()

while read -a lst # this declares lst as a normal array and loads each line in fields
do id=${lst[0]}                            # field 0 assigned as the id
   lst=( ${lst[@]:1} )                     # lst assigned itself MINUS the first field
   cnt[$id]=${#lst[@]}                     # count for this id assigned # of  remaining elements in lst
   set[$id]="${lst[@]}"                    # set for id assigned the space-delimited elements of lst
   for k in ${lst[@]}                      # this will iterate k as each item in lst
   do  lookup["$k"]="${lookup["$k"]} $id"  # additively assigns, space delimited, this id as having this string
   done
done<dataset                               # when done reading the file, each key has a list of which id's it's on

# now we analyze our accumulated data
for id1 in ${!cnt[@]}                      # for every id (cnt has how many strings for each, ${!cnt[@]} is all the ids)
do  for k in ${set["$id1"]}                # iterate k over each string id1 had
    do  for id2 in ${lookup["$k"]}         # iterate id2 over each id that had this string
        do  [[ "$id1" == "$id2" ]] && continue # skip when both id pointers are looking at the same record
            case "${set["$id2"]}" in       # look at the whole set of strings assigned to id2 as a space-delimited string
            ### ==>> CAVEAT: might needed to be "$k "*|*" $k "*|*" $k") so that AAA doesn't match AA
            ### "$k "*|*" $k "*|*" $k") hitlst["$id1 $id2"]="${hitlst["$id1 $id2"]} $k";
            *$k*) hitlst["$id1 $id2"]="${hitlst["$id1 $id2"]} $k"; # when the current key from $id1 is anywhere in it
                  (( hitcnt["$id1 $id2"]++ )) ;;                   # increment the matches per pair of ids
            esac
            if (( ${hitcnt["$id1 $id2"]}0 > ${hitcnt["$id1"]}0 ))  # if matches/pair > stored max for id1
            then hitcnt["$id1"]=${hitcnt["$id1 $id2"]}             # upgrade to the new max
                 hitid["$id1"]="$id2"                              # and remember to report which rec while we're at it
            fi
       done
    done
done

printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" "ID" "Longest Combo" "#strings" "[List of strings] / [matches] / matching ID"
for id in ${!cnt[@]}   # again, for every id
do  id2=${hitid[$id]}  # and again, this is the rec that had the most matches in case you wanted it (not requested)
    # print the fields with some formatting to align them
    printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" "$id" "${hitcnt[$id]}" "${cnt[$id]}" "[${set[$id]}] / [${hitlst["$id $id2"]# }] / $id2"
done

$: proc
 ID Longest Combo  #strings [List of strings] / [matches] / matching ID
  1             3         5 [AAA BBBA ACA CCD ABADA] / [AAA ACA CCD] / 2
  2             3         3 [AAA ACA CCD] / [AAA ACA CCD] / 1
  3             1         3 [AAB BBAC DDAD] / [DDAD] / 4
  4             4         4 [AAA ACA DDAD CCD] / [AAA ACA DDAD CCD] / 5
  5             4         4 [AAA ACA DDAD CCD] / [AAA ACA DDAD CCD] / 4
```

I added a few fields and tweaked the output formatting, but you get the idea. Shouldn't take *too* long with only 3k recs.

Comment: If it's too slow I'd do it in Perl.

Comment: Thanks very much for this! I've spent some time playing around with it today and it seems to do the job perfectly (although validating by hand is difficult...). The run time is perfectly acceptable and bash is also more than fine!

Comment: Glad I could help! Accept the solution? If you really want to stroke my ego, feel free to upvote it too, lol. It was a fun little project. Did you need the output visually aligned, or just delimited? Tabs would look like hell on a screen but work better for loading to a spreadsheet...and would get rid of all the ugly-ish formatting code in those printf's/

Comment: BTW, do you want comments to explain the logic, or is it clear enough?

Comment: Nope it's perfectly fine as is thanks! I already upvoted but I don't have the juice for it to show. I will accept though!

Comment: Check for that possible caveat. 'AAAA' will give `*AAA*` a false match, but just swap in the new but still commented line, it'll fix that.

Comment: Just noticed that some of the IDs are coming up multiple times with different results (even with the new line of code). Don't suppose I could send you my dataset? No worries if not, I appreciate how much you'be done already!

Comment: link the dataset if you want. You say it's outputting the same id multiple times with different data?

Comment: I feel silly for not asking sooner - are the identifiers possibly nonunique in the input?

Comment: no dup keys in ypour input file. Definitely dup keys in the output. Will debug.

Comment: huh. I switched the formatting to just simple tab delimitation and it *seems* to have fixed it. Weird. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 2):

here is a prototype `awk` solution.  Note that due to symmetry you just need (i,j) entries for `i<j`.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) a[$1,$i]; size=$1; next} 
               {for(i=$1+1;i<=size;i++) 
                  {for(j=2;j<=NF;j++) 
                     if((i,$j) in a) {c[$1,i]++; list[$1,i]=list[$1,i] FS $j}
                   if(max[$1]<c[$1,i]) {max[$1]=c[$1,i]; maxM[$1]=i}} 
                   if(maxM[$1]) print $1,maxM[$1],"->",max[$1],list[$1,maxM[$1]]}' file{,}

1 2 -> 3  AAA ACA CCD
2 4 -> 3  AAA ACA CCD
3 4 -> 1  DDAD
4 5 -> 4  AAA ACA DDAD CCD
```

can be simplified little more, I guess match length can be computed from the list size.

**Explanation**
Double-pass algorithm, store all elements per record id in a lookup table; also set size. In the second pass, compare the current row for all rows with higher indices. Find the intersection size and record the maximum, corresponding row and matched fields.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I assume the number after the '->' is the field corresponding to the longest combination? If so in your example I think it should be 3 (AAA, ACA and CCD present in 1 and 2 but DDAD not present in either).

Comment: Yes, in other terms, it's the number of common terms between the given row indices.  For example for (1,2) -> 3 there are 3 terms between row 1 and 2 (So due to symmetry it's the same between rows 2 and 1.  Moreover, it's the longest match compared to other rows with 1 (there can be ties).  Your terminology is little different.  When you say longest combination, does it mean the number of elements or the max length of the matched string?  For example for (3,4) the number of elements common is 1 (namely DDAD), but it's length is 4.

Comment: Sorry - I'll try and clarify! When I say longest combination I mean the number of elements, the length of the strings doesn't matter for me. So in the case of 3,4 it would as you say be one (DDAD).